# How does Wikipedia create images from <math> element?

Tags: javascript, latex, wikipedia

I've noticed that, by using that `<math>` element on Wikipedia, I can input `LaTeX` code and have a `LaTeX` result. The code, however, is not maintained on the actual page after being edited; it is somehow saved as an image element with a (meaningful?) source (e.g. [this picture/equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Conor_S._O%27Brien#ex)). The example given's source is `.../math/a/9/7/a97cd92ab2cdf4de6ea533805627f7f3.png`.

I was wondering if there is some way I can manipulate this (i.e. create a script that would interpret a user's `LaTeX` input and convert it to a source), ***or*** if I could use whatever code/process Wikipedia uses to achieve this. The source appears to be in base 16 (hexadecimal)--does this have some sort of meaning?

The main question I'm asking is: how can I use Wikipedia's `LaTeX` interpreter to my advantage? I am trying to use it in Google Sites, which does not allow native JavaScript to be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia, AFAIK, uses TeX to render the image serverside, when you submit the page. The hex just appears to be a hash, probably of original content.

Use MathJax (heavy) or KaTeX (light) to render LaTeX on clientside into HTML. If you want to render serverside (to an image), you will want to use TeX itself.

I never used Google Sites, and don't know its restrictions.

Comment: It (Google Sites) doesn't allow JavaScript to be referenced or imported; no custom JS.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You can have custom JS, but isolated to the HTML box and heavily restricted. See [this discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/sites/pnPzm-TRp4g/cZVryBkfCA8J). Your best bet for user-input LaTeX seems to be to switch to a less opinionated hosting solution.

Comment: Do you know of anything like you suggested?

Comment: Sorry, no; I never needed such hosting; and besides, I don't know what your requirements are. The thread I linked suggests [Weebly](http://www.weebly.com/) as Google Sites alternative, but I have not tried myself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above describes the rendering before 2016, which was based on filtered TeX using texvc. In 2016 a new rendering was introduced, which generates MathML with optional fallback SVG or even PNG images. However, currently, all browsers display the SVG images unless they are marked as known good by the installation of browser-specific add-ons as described in the [help page of the math extension.](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math#Viewing_math) Section [3](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1785/W48.pdf) of the corresponding research paper, how pages with math are rendered in a 14 step process.